# How can I change the rabbitmq persist message location on Windows?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, containers, messaging, persist

For our system we mark important messages with the delivery mode = 2, and are sending them on durable exchanges and queue's.  The problem is that rabbitmq is being hosted on a docker container, and if that container goes down, the messages that have been persisted are lost upon container restart.

I want to know if there is a way to change the location of the persistence of messages to a mounted volume instead of the container-backed disk, and if so how.  I also currently cant figure out where the messages are actually being persisted right now, and so finding to config for that is definitely a start, I'm just not sure where this is set as I cant find anything related to mnesia, and that seems to be a default for some people.  This change to location could be at runtime or not, it is unimportant to me.

Also for help, try to keep in mind that all of this is very new to me so I'm not the most educated on how this system functions in all of its glory, so simple explanations will help a good deal more than those with unnecessarily complex solutions.  Let me know if I can provide any other helpful info.

Comment: A good starting point is the Docker documentation on [storage](https://docs.docker.com/storage/), and more specifically the chapter on [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: So I've read a decent amount on that page, I feel like mounting the container to the volume would help fix the problem, I just cant figure out how to actually do so.  I currently start all microservices at the same time, and only need to mount the one messagequeue service to a volume.  Do you know how to mount a volume after spinning up the container, or can it only be done at start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [right here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) in the RabbitMQ documentation.

Create the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` file with the following contents to change the persistent data location:

```
MNESIA_DIR=/path/to/mounted/volume
```

Note that the `RABBITMQ_` prefix is not necessary for variables defined in `rabbitmq-env.conf`

Comment: I've read that page about a million times and can't really figure out what it is saying.  Where should I actually put this file?

Comment: It's literally in my answer: "Create the /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf file with the following contents...". Please don't forget to accept my answer here, thank you.

Comment: Also, see this - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/WRCJ3VeEaqE/WrNT2WkhGAAJ

Comment: Thanks, for Windows I had to volume map the MNESIA_DIR to a location of my host, and I dont think I have a rabbit-mq.conf anywhere still...  Have not yet figured out how to have that location become overwritten every time the container is removed and restarted yet though